# IE9 not displaying correctly footer

Tags: internet-explorer-9, typo3, meta-tags, doctype

I have trouble with IE9 displaying footer. http://www.advinsure.nl/
It's TYPO3 cms website. The version of TYPO3 is 4.

On the main page it's correct, but if you click on "Opdrachtgevers", footer messes up. 
If i click on Compatibility button in IE9, the footer is correctly displayed.

**What i've tried:** i've added this tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` (also tried "8" instead of "Edge"),  which must make IE9 work in the compatibility mode, it doesn't help.

Also i've changed DOCTYPE (i've manually changed it in the templates folder of the project on the server) from

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`.

to

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

But when i check the source, it is none of the above:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

How do i make footer displayed correctly? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a TYPO3-Website (like it appears to be from the tagging), the doctype is set by TYPO3, not the template.

The TypoScript setting you are looking for is `config.doctype`, its documentation is here:
http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/6/#id1556666 (for TYPO3 4.7)

Look for the "doctype" setting, there's a list of accepted values.